# Creating new MySQL user: what does the host matching mean?

Tags: mysql

I am following a tutorial on udemy and I'm stuck setting up a new user. I have managed to get through the best part of it but the tutorial uses phpmyadmin, now I'm on workbench.

Can anyone explain what the "limit to host matching" is used for? Does it only allow access to users with a certain IP address or domain name? I am just running on a local server and I could use root for the project but hey, I have to learn it at some stage so why not now?

Comment: It limits access to a particular host or host pattern. Usually you set it to `%` or "any host" but sometimes you'll want to lock it down.

Comment: could you define the word host in this scenario? is it an ip address or a web address or something?

Comment: Don't use an IDE tag just because you use that IDE, and rhat includes the MySQL Workbench. The question is about MySQL itself. Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: "Host" means [Fully Qualified Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (FQDN), or in other words, the DNS name corresponding with the host requesting access. This is obtained through a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) which converts an arbitrary IP to hostname *if* a `PTR` record is present.

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly a MySQL Workbench question, but nonetheless essential for user creation: the host part can be either a hostname (which will be resolved by MySQL to an IP address) or an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6). These values determine from which host a user can connect as seen from the host the MySQL server runs on (e.g. `localhost` means the MySQL server machine, not the machine you connect from, unless it's the same box of course). For each of the variants you can use wildcards and placeholders, to match a range of machines.

This page of the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html) describes the matching process and shows examples:

```
The following table shows how various combinations of User and Host values in the user table apply to incoming connections.

╔═════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ User Value  ║          Host Value           ║                                          Permissible Connections                                          ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 'fred'      ║ 'h1.example.net'              ║ fred, connecting from h1.example.net                                                                      ║
║ ''          ║ 'h1.example.net'              ║ Any user, connecting from h1.example.net                                                                  ║
║ 'fred'      ║ '%'                           ║ fred, connecting from any host                                                                            ║
║ ''          ║ '%'                           ║ Any user, connecting from any host                                                                        ║
║ 'fred'      ║ '%.example.net'               ║ fred, connecting from any host in the example.net domain                                                  ║
║ 'fred'      ║ 'x.example.%'                 ║ fred, connecting from x.example.net, x.example.com, x.example.edu, and so on; this is probably not useful ║
║ 'fred'      ║ '198.51.100.177'              ║ fred, connecting from the host with IP address 198.51.100.177                                             ║
║ 'fred'      ║ '198.51.100.%'                ║ fred, connecting from any host in the 198.51.100 class C subnet                                           ║
║ 'fred'      ║ '198.51.100.0/255.255.255.0'  ║ Same as previous example                                                                                  ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```